# Finding all possible combinations of truth values to well-formed formulas occuring in the given formula in C

Tags: c, formula, truthtable, well-formed

I want to write a truth table evaluator for a given formula like in this site.
http://jamie-wong.com/experiments/truthtabler/SLR1/
Operators are:

```
-  (negation)   
&  (and)        
|  (or)       
>  (implication)     
=  (equivalence)
```

So far I made this

```
-(-(a& b) > ( -((a|-s)| c )| d))
```

given this formula my output is

```
    abdsR
    TTTT
    TTTF
    TTFT
    TTFF
    TFTT
    TFTF
    TFFT
    TFFF
    FTTT
    FTTF
    FTFT 
    FTFF
    FFTT
    FFTF
    FFFT
    FFFF
```

I am having difficulties with the evaluating part.
I created an array which in I stored indises of parenthesis if it helps,namely 
7-3, 17-12, 20-11, 23-9, 24-1
I also checked the code in http://www.stenmorten.com/English/llc/source/turth_tables_ass4.c
,however I didn't get it.

Comment: The output table needs to have the `R` column filled in. Also, you might want to explain how the `implication` operator is supposed to work in a truth table.

Comment: @user3386109 implication (A > B) is equivalent to (¬A | B).

Comment: YesI know,but I couldn't find the R value.implication operator returns false if the first operand true the  second operand false 1>0=0 otherwise =1

Answer (score 0):

Writing an *[operator precedence parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser)* to evaluate *[infix notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation)* expressions is not an easy task. However, the *[shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm)* is a good place to start.